# Cannot access values from get_query_var() in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am busy developing a WordPress application and I need to be able to pass url parameters using WordPress functions. I use `add_query_arg()` function to add a url parameter. However, when I try to get the passed value in the other page using `get_query_var()` nothing gets returned. When I used `$_GET['var_name']` the values gets returned.

What is the possible cause of this situation? I can successfully add arguments to the url but I am not able to access them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I managed to get the `get_query_var()` function to work.
To use the two functions successfully, you need to add the query vars to wordpress's query vars array. Here is a code sample.

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "query_var_name";
 return $vars;
}

//Add custom query vars
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

Now you can use `get_query_var()` and `add_query_arg()` as follows:

Add the query var and value

```
add_query_arg( array('query_var_name' => 'value'), old_url );
```

Get the query var value

```
$value = get_query_var('query_var_name');
```

More information and code samples can be found at the Codex: [get_query_var](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) and [add_query_arg](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)

Comment: this answer doesn't explain where one would call add_filter, add_query_arg, etc. It could be considerably improved with more detail.

Answer (score 8):

To troubleshoot, what variables are being used in the request use following code

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

Comment: Help with troubleshooting and gathering debugging details does not constitute posting an answer. If you need more details, post a comment under the question. Your non-resolving guidance should have been a comment.

Answer (score 3):

If you check out the Codex, you'll see you actually need to do some fiddling to get WP to start reading your query string.

[Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var#Custom_Query_Vars) (under Custom Query Vars)

Excerpt:

> In order to be able to add and work with your own custom query vars that you append to URLs (eg: "mysite com/some_page/?my_var=foo" - for example using add_query_arg()) you need to add them to the public query variables available to WP_Query. These are built up when WP_Query instantiates, but fortunately are passed through a filter 'query_vars' before they are actually used to populate the $query_vars property of WP_Query.

Answer (score 0):

get_query_var() only retrieves public query variables that are recognized by WP_Query. This means that if you create your own custom URLs with their own query variables, get_query_var() will not retrieve them without some further work.

[Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/)