# Why does not work with $_REQUEST

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, url, coordinate

Passing values to my `marker` function works fine with hard coded values, but not when I use values from $_REQUEST.

I have a WordPress plugin to Google Maps. I am trying to get the latitude and longitude from the URL.

If I call `marker` with constant, it works (displays marker on Google Map):

```
marker("35.415156","25.141561");
```

But if I call marker function with the `$_REQUEST` variable, it does not work (does not display marker on Google Map):

```
marker($_REQUEST['coordx'],$_REQUEST['coordy'])
```

My code is:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_g_map_options","g_map_nopriv_options_callback");

g_map_nopriv_options_callback($_REQUEST['coordx'],$_REQUEST['coordy']);

function g_map_nopriv_options_callback($lat_coord,$lng_coord) {                     
    $lat_coord2 = $lat_coord;
    $lng_coord2 = $lng_coord;

    $response = $response."<marker id='6' size='48' name='' animation='DROP' lat='".$lat_coord2."' lng='".$lng_coord2."' description='' img='' />";
}
```

Why is there does it not work when the values are read from the $_REQUEST variable?

Comment: Have you tested printing out $_REQUEST['coordx'] to make sure that you have a value? Moreover you should compare the types.

Comment: perfectly print value of requested variable. but if i put into marker function as argument, is not work

Comment: Can you provide more of your code?  How are you displaying them?

Comment: i dont display directly, i put value of requested variable into a global variable. Global variables is in argument of <marker> (lat, lng).

Comment: if I print $request variable after the printing I get "Header already sent.... error". If I do not print, just put into variable I do not get "Header already sent...error";

Perhaps does it mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't simply hand the request vars to the back end.

You have to register the query vars to be able to use them within your plugins and themes.

You can see this topic it will help you understand how to register an use query vars.

[WordPress get_query_var()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379543/wordpress-get-query-var/21159283#21159283)

Comment: I add this function to my plugin file:
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = 'coordx';
 return $vars;

}

//Add custom query vars
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );


if I call on front-end $value = get_query_var('coordx');, it is ok (print coordx.

But I can not call in plugin backend function. Why? I would like to put variable to plugin function.